# Developing a website using remote server

Tags: wordpress, server, hosting, collaboration

I have been searching for a broad answer to this question for a while.

I am developing a website using wordpress and have a fair amount of css/html/php/js knowledge. In the past, I have made websites on my local machine and then registered them with a domain name.

This time, a friend has offered to help as he has experience with the marketing/business aspects of web development.

As I said, we are using wordpress, and I would like us both to be able to access the website as it would be viewed online, as well as the backend in order to make changes and complete development however we see fit.

**I have considered a number of options for how to do this, but I would like some guidance and see what people recommend. I see my options as this:**

**(1)** Meet up with him and host the wordpress site on the local IP to edit together.

**(2)** Enable port forwarding so that he can access the wordpress remotely and we can edit together.

**(3)** Load Ubuntu onto an old machine and host the website using DynDNS.

**(4)** Buy actual server space and host the website with the express intention of editing it remotely and later hosting it to a new domain.

**(5)** Using git or a repo system (this idea is not as good because he does not have experience with such a system and does not seem ideal for web hosting).

Which of these would seem ideal? If we ended up looking to build more sites, which of these options would be best?

Thanks! Also, if there is an old StackOverflow that answers this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Voting to close as this is primarily opinion based. There is no right or wrong answer, different solutions work in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have used options 3 and 4 with great results. Being that I already have server space and it was not a problem to host it there. I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm pretty sure GitHub is an option too. I've never used it but I think it would work for this.